# iMessage conversations on iPad 2 are not appearing on my iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, messages

I've just bought myself an iPhone 5, I've set up iCloud on it and synced it with my iPad. However, all of the iMessage conversations I had on my iPad are not showing up on my iPhone's iMessages. How can I load and continue to have my old iMessage conversations from my iPad to my iphone?

Answer (score 2):

They are not stored in iCloud (or the iMessage server). This is for your own privacy. 
They cannot be redownloaded.